# Pass a python list to an SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, json

```
res = db.execute("""
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000.0) AS decimal(6,1))
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId 
INNER JOIN Calendar c
ON r.DayId = c.DayId
WHERE c.WeekCodeInYear BETWEEN 1 AND 12
AND 
c.YearId = 2014
AND p.Distributor IN (%s)
GROUP BY c.WeekCodeInYear """ % _studios)
```

`_studios` is a Python list and is a part of a JSON object. It can be read as:

```
["WARNER","TF1","GAUMONT","PATHE","STUDIOCANAL","FRANCETV","M6SND"]
```

However when I try and execute this I get an error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (207, "Invalid column name 'u'WARNER', u'TF1', 
u'GAUMONT', u'PATHE', u'STUDIOCANAL', u'FRANCETV', u'M6SND''.DB-Lib error message 20018, 
severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL
```

The Database however has all the columns specified. I guess it has to do with the format. Not sure though.

The query when printed in the command prompt can be seen as:

```
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000.0) AS decimal(6,1))
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN Calendar c
ON r.DayId = c.DayId
WHERE c.WeekCodeInYear BETWEEN 1 AND 12
AND
c.YearId = 2014
AND p.Distributor IN ([u'WARNER', u'TF1', u'GAUMONT', u'PATHE', u'STUDIOCANAL',
u'FRANCETV', u'M6SND'])
GROUP BY c.WeekCodeInYear
```

I notice the `[` `]` in the `p.distributor` line which is the probably issue?

Comment: This is trivially vulnerable to injection attacks, even in the "fixed" version where you concatenate the list into a comma-delimited string.  Use whatever parameterized query implementation your SQL API provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the issue. You're using the `__repr__` version of the list. Instead, use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function to make it into a usable string, combined with a list comprehension to quote the strings:

```
"""SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000.0) AS decimal(6,1))
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN Calendar c
ON r.DayId = c.DayId
WHERE c.WeekCodeInYear BETWEEN 1 AND 12
AND
c.YearId = 2014
AND p.Distributor IN ({})
GROUP BY c.WeekCodeInYear """.format(', '.join(["'" + studio + "'" for studio in _studios]))
```

This, however, becomes very hard to maintain and read if there's more complex queries with more parameters. The above solution's format statement is already hard to understand, this will get only worse.

It is also vulnerable to SQL injection, as roippi has pointed out. They are also right with their suggestion to use parametrized queries.

Comment: This converts the string as `("WARNER", "TF1", "GAUMONT", "PATHE", "STUDIOCANAL", "FRANCTV", "M6SND")`. So basically the double quotes dont work no? What I need is `('WARNER', 'TF1', 'GAUMONT', 'PATHE', 'STUDIOCANAL', 'FRANCTV', 'M6SND')`

Comment: Whoops, overlooked your requirement there, but I've fixed it now. :)

Comment: Now this solution doesnot read the string at all :( The previous one read the string but with `"`

Comment: Works for me with Python 2.7 and 3.4, what problem do you have?

Comment: Works now! Probably some sytax issue from my end. But yes I have about 5 more parameters to add. In that case this solution would become infeasible?

Comment: Not infeasible, but either you'd have to write a utility function that formats those fields like you want or follow roippi's advice on using parametrized queries. Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)/upvote :P

Comment: Tried doing the function bit, but unable to get it. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: This discussion is going off-topic, please ask another question or approach the guys in the Python SO chat.